# CSS resizes inconsistently when browser zoomed

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm working on a simple CSS animation and came across a curious problem.

When animating several small divs, if I zoom in or out on Chrome/Firefox the heights of the divs becomes inconsistent - despite them all sharing the same size styles.

Is there any way to address this using CSS? I want the bars to maintain a consistent height without regard to the zoom level. I realize this is something of an edge case, but want to cover as many bases as possible!

Example is [here](https://codepen.io/BrandonKerr/full/pLrEXP/).

HTML

```
<div class='animation-box animate'>
  <div class="animation-bar"></div>
  <div class="animation-bar"></div>
  <div class="animation-bar"></div>
  <div class="animation-bar"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.animation-box {
  width: 100px;
}

.animation-bar {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: bargraph;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background-color: #0d97c1;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 2px;
}

@keyframes bargraph {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 10%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem of subpixel rendering. The issue here is that when you are zooming, the space between two bars will have to snap to a given pixel on your screen.

If you have a **3px** margin @ **150% zoom**, the computed space is **4,5px**. Meaning that the zoomed space on screen will be **inconsistently rendered at 4 or 5px**.

On a regular CPU computed dom, your bar will be placed at the closest value, producing those weird gaps.

What you could do to minimize the effect is applying some GPU rendered CSS (opposed to the regular CPU rendering) which is way better at rendering subpixel graphics.

One way of doing that is applying transforms.

```css
.animation-box {
  width: 55px;
  margin: 0 15px 0 -5px;
}

.animation-bar {
  animation: bargraph 1s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: top left;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #0d97c1;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

@keyframes bargraph {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  25% {
    transform: scaleX(.8);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleX(.6);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scaleX(.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='animation-box animate'>
  <div class="animation-bar"></div>
  <div class="animation-bar"></div>
  <div class="animation-bar"></div>
  <div class="animation-bar"></div>
</div>
```

I recommend an excellent article on Smashing Magazine on that topic : [CSS GPU Animation: Doing It Right](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/gpu-animation-doing-it-right/)

Answer (score 1):

What about a simplification with only one element and less of code:

```css
.animation-bar {
  animation: bargraph 1.5s infinite linear alternate;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#0d97c1 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-position:0 0;
  background-size: 100% 5px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

@keyframes bargraph {
  0% {
    background-size: 100% 5px;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 10% 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation-bar"></div>
```

Comment: This is a great approach, but I actually want each of the four bars to be moving at different rates, to look like some sort of bar graph or equalizer - might have culled too much of the CSS.

Comment: Also doesn't seem to totally resolve the issue - the spacing still gets a bit weird though the bars themselves hold up.

I think the only way to actually deal with this would be using an image instead.

Comment: @Bricky we can use the same think to deal with each bar alone, here i use repeat but we can have multiple gradient and animat each one alone ;) here is few ideas : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49416454/resizing-span-on-hover-first-and-second-child/49416553#49416553